# Is there a javascript library which can help me in rails parameter naming conventions?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I would like to add a library to my app which can help me in manipulation query parameters which conform to the rails parameter naming conventions.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions

If it can handle hashes and maps then it would be perfect.

Comment: Why not produce conformant parameters from the start?

Comment: I need to deal with arrays... And I also need to conform to Rails parameter naming conventions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $.param function does exaclty the thing I want:

```
$.param({category: 'blue', cate:['red', 'green'], gru:{cat: 'brown', mice: 'glue'}})
```

produces

```
"category=blue&cate%5B%5D=red&cate%5B%5D=green&gru%5Bcat%5D=brown&gru%5Bmice%5D=glue"
```